# How to plot sigmoid probability curve in Scikitlearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to recreate this image using Python given 2 classes and their associated predicted probability from a classifier.

**I want to see something like this:**
[image: sigmoid curve]

It's not working though, as I get a mostly linear line.
**NOTE: I know this data shown is currently suspect and/or bad. I need to tune the input & model, but wanted to look at the plot

Basically, I thought I'd "correct" the predict_proba() output so they are all with respect to the "0" class (meaning if it predicted "1" class, the probability that it's a "0" class is 1-(1classProbability)  such that 95% prediction it's class "1" becomes a 5% change it's class "0".  Then sort in order of my corrected predicition value and end up with something sigmoid-ish.

**Unfortunately, I end up with this:**
[image]

Here's a chunk of my python where I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to plot the probability sigmoid:

```
###########################
 ## I removed my original Python code because it was very, very wrong so as to avoid any confusion.
###########################
```

For reference, below is the plot in Matlab that I'm trying to replicate in my Python model.

```
%Build the model
mdl = fitglm(X, Y, 'distr', 'binomial', 'link', 'logit')
%Build the sigmoid model
B = mdl.Coefficients{:, 1};
Z = mdl.Fitted.LinearPredictor
yhat = glmval(B, X, 'logit'); 
figure, scatter(Z, yhat), hold on,
gscatter(Z, zeros(length(X),1)-0.1, Y) % plot original classes
hold off, xlabel('\bf Z'),  grid on,  ylim([-0.2 1.05])
title('\bf Predicted Probability of each record')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more pythonic ways to do this, but here's what I was able to come up with in the end:

(Keep in mind, the data is not well-separated in this case, so the curve doen't have a traditional look with classes separated at the 0.50 point on the sigmoid curve.)

```
#############################################################################
#### Draws a sigmoid probability plot from prediction results ###############
#############################################################################
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
print ('-'*40)

# make the predictions (class) and also get the prediction probabilities 
y_train_predict = clf.predict(X_train)
y_train_predictProbas = clf.predict_proba(X_train)
y_train_predictProbas = y_train_predictProbas[:, 1]

y_test_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
y_test_predictProbas = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
y_test_predictProbas = y_test_predictProbas[:, 1]

#Get the thetas from the model
thetas = clf.coef_[0]
intercept = clf.intercept_[0]
print 'thetas='
print thetas
print 'intercept='
print intercept

#Display the predictors and their associated Thetas
for idx, x in enumerate(thetas):
    print "Predictor: " + str(labels[idx+1]) + "=" + str(x)

#append intercept to thetas (because scikitlearn doesn't normally output theta0
interceptAndThetas = np.append([intercept],thetas)
X_testWithThetaZero = []
for row in X_test:
    X_testWithThetaZero.append(np.append([1],row))

#Calculate the dot product for plotting the sigmoid
dotProductResult = []    
for idx, x in enumerate(X_testWithThetaZero):
    dotProductResult.append(np.dot( x, interceptAndThetas))    


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

wrongDotProducts = []
rightDotProducts = []
#Build the plot
for idx in range(0,len(dotProductResult)):
    #plot the predicted value on the sigmoid curve
    if y_test[idx] == 1:
        ax1.scatter(dotProductResult[idx], y_test_predictProbas[idx], c=['green'],linewidths=0.0)
    else:
        ax1.scatter(dotProductResult[idx], y_test_predictProbas[idx], c=['black'],linewidths=0.0)

    #plot the actual
    if y_test[idx] == 1:
        ax1.scatter(dotProductResult[idx], y_test[idx], c=['green'],linewidths=0.0)
        #determine which ones are "wrong" so we can make a histogram
        if y_test_predictProbas[idx] < 0.5:
            wrongDotProducts.append(dotProductResult[idx])
        else:
            rightDotProducts.append(dotProductResult[idx])
    else:
        ax1.scatter(dotProductResult[idx], y_test[idx], c=['black'],linewidths=0.0)
        #determine which ones are "wrong" so we can make a histogram
        if y_test_predictProbas[idx] > 0.5:
            wrongDotProducts.append(dotProductResult[idx])
        else:
            rightDotProducts.append(dotProductResult[idx])        

#plt.xlim([-0.05, numInstances + 0.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.grid(which="major", axis='both',markevery=0.10)  # which='major',
plt.ylabel('Prediction Probability')
plt.title('Sigmoid Curve & Histogram of Predictions')


## Add a histogram to show where the correct/incorrect prediction distributions
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.hist(wrongDotProducts, bins=[-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], hatch="/", color="black", alpha=0.2)
ax2.hist(rightDotProducts, bins=[-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], hatch="\\", color="green", alpha=0.2)

ax2.set_ylabel('Histogram Count of Actual Class\n1=Green 0=Black')
ax2.set_xlabel('')
ax2.set_title('')
plt.show()
```

[image]